# Gulp-Nodeman: Unable to run executable: "node" (env. issue)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, build-process

I'm currently in the process of adding "livereload" capabilities to my current build process. Previously, I would need to "build" the output and restart my server using `node server.js` every time I made a change. A few SO solutions mentioned using "gulp-nodemon" to implement this.

The server file below works just fine when executed using `node server.js`. However, when I attempt to start it using nodeman and gulp, I get the following output:

```
[11:36:48] [nodemon] v1.7.0
[11:36:48] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs
[11:36:48] [nodemon] watching: /debug/***/*
[11:36:48] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
{ [Error: spawn cmd ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/c', 'node server.js' ] }
[11:36:48] [nodemon] unable to run executable: "node"
```

Using `node -v` I get "v4.1.0"

And I am running my cmd window as an Administrator on Win8. Any/all help is appreciated.

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('server', function(done){
    // listen for changes
    livereload.listen();
    // configure nodemon
    nodemon({
        // script that runs app
        script: 'server.js',
        watch: '/debug/**'
    }).on('error', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// CONST
var PORT = 3000;
var serverDirectory = __dirname;

// Static Assets
app.use('/source', express.static(serverDirectory + '/debug'));
app.use('/libraries', express.static(serverDirectory + '/bower_components'));
app.use('/assets', express.static(serverDirectory + '/debug/assets'));

// Redirect
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    return response.redirect('/app/');
});

// ROOT
app.get('/app/*', function(request, response) {
    return response.sendFile(serverDirectory + '/debug/index.html');
});

// Start app/server
var server = app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT + '...');
});
```

**Update:**
I have `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` in my System's PATH, and I have verified that node.exe lives at that location.

**Update:**
Navigating to my "node_modules" directory, when I try to run the provided `gulp test` command that comes with this package, I get the exact same error. Seems to imply that this is an environment issue.

Comment: Check out `Controlling shutdown of your script` section in https://github.com/remy/nodemon. That might help.

Comment: After reading that section, I'm not sure it contains anything that would be helpful here.